# Access children of an object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, parent, children

I am trying to access the children of an object in TypeScript.

So object1 is a child of Object. When I console log Object (parent), I clearly see the property 'Children'. If I expand Children, I see Object1.

[image]

Normally in JavaScript, I would do something like

```
var child = Object.children[0];
```

However, when I do that in TypeScript, it gives a syntax error saying

> error TS2339: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'DisplayObject'.

Is there a different way to do it in TS?

**EDIT**

A sample code:

```
  this.game.world.children.forEach(function(child){
        var constructorString: string = child.constructor.toString();
        var className: string = constructorString.match(/\w+/g)[1];
        if(className=='AcheivmentButton'){
          for(var i=0; i<child.children.length; i++)
            children.push(child.children[i]);
        }
      })
```

Comment: Cast it to the type you are expecting it to be? It its not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Maybe provide a more extensive example?

Comment: What library are you using? Your problem mainly seems to be that you do not have typings (a .d.ts file) for the javascript library you are using. You can read more about how this works in the typescript handbook http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a different way to do it in TS?

No. This is simply a discrepancy in the definition for the object you are using.

The quickest way around is to simply use an assertion:

```
var child = (Object as any).children[0];
```

## More

- on assertion : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html
- on ambient declarations and their best effort nature : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html